# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.modeling_albert'

Tags: python, module, huggingface-transformers

I am following a notebook and trying to execute the following code on colab:

```
from simpletransformers.classification import MultiLabelClassificationModel
model = MultiLabelClassificationModel('roberta', '/content/roberta', args={})
```

But I am running into `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.modeling_albert'`

I have made sure to install the correct version of `!pip install "simpletransformers"==0.34.4`

Some guidance on ways to load to roberta model would be useful.

Comment: Try `pip list` on your command line and see if the package is indeed installed at the dir you intended.

Comment: I have installed transformers and I believe that modeling_albert should be situated within the transformers library. I am trying to figure out which old transformers module has the following modeling.albert and MultiLabelClassificationModel within it @VaeJiang